# how can i loop the $interval of the time

Tags: php

i tried all i could but could not come up with the solution ....how can  i loop the $interval of the time ....

Here is the function from my CodeIgniter contoller :

```
  public function calculate_time_lap() {
        $formate = "%h:%i";
        $in = $this->input->post('checkin');

        foreach ($in as $checkin) {
            $datetime1 = date_create($checkin);
        }

        $out = $this->input->post('checkout');
        foreach ($out as $checkout) {
            $datetime2 = date_create($checkout);
        }

        $interval = date_diff($datetime2, $datetime1);
        $times = $interval->format($formate);

        echo $this->add_time($times);
        //add_time is function to add array value of time
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand what you want to do, could you complete your question by an example?

Comment: i want $interval to be an array...

Comment: where checkin and checkout are array...

Comment: but you set $interval outside of your foreach loops, what do you think $datetime1 and $datetime2 are? They are not arrays !

Comment: they are i tried it by printing it ...

Comment: let me make it more clear..i hav passed array in checkin and checkout and i'm trying to get result ($interval in array ) like  $interval[0] = date_diff($datetime2, $datetime1); & $interval[1] = date_diff($datetime2, $datetime1); how can i make this ..with this code??

Comment: They are not arrays, they are DateTime Objects, and you only have one date in $datetime1 or $datetime2 because you are resetting their values each time the loop is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an array of datetimes for checkin and checkout.

```
$in = $this->input->post('checkin');
foreach ($in as $checkin) {
    $datetime_array1[] = date_create($checkin);
}

$out = $this->input->post('checkout');
foreach ($out as $checkout) {
    $datetime_array2[] = date_create($checkout);
}
```

Then for each of them set the interval in an array :

```
foreach ($datetime_array1 as $key => $datetime1) {
    $datetime2 = $datetime_array2[$key];
    $interval[] = date_diff($datetime2, $datetime1);
}
```

I don't know if your input is correct so I give you a sample of what it does :

```
$datetime_array1[] = date_create('2000-01-01');
$datetime_array1[] = date_create('2000-01-02');
$datetime_array1[] = date_create('2000-01-03');

$datetime_array2[] = date_create('2000-02-01');
$datetime_array2[] = date_create('2000-03-02');
$datetime_array2[] = date_create('2000-04-03');

foreach ($datetime_array1 as $key => $datetime1) {
    $datetime2 = $datetime_array2[$key];
    $interval[] = date_diff($datetime2, $datetime1);
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r($interval, TRUE) . '</pre>';
```

Returns :

```
Array
(
[0] => DateInterval Object
    (
        [y] => 0
        [m] => 1
        [d] => 0
        [h] => 0
        [i] => 0
        [s] => 0
        [invert] => 1
        [days] => 31
    )

[1] => DateInterval Object
    (
        [y] => 0
        [m] => 2
        [d] => 0
        [h] => 0
        [i] => 0
        [s] => 0
        [invert] => 1
        [days] => 60
    )

[2] => DateInterval Object
    (
        [y] => 0
        [m] => 3
        [d] => 0
        [h] => 0
        [i] => 0
        [s] => 0
        [invert] => 1
        [days] => 91
    )
```

)

Comment: Cannot use object of type DateTime as array .....it giving error sumthing like this